# shutdownNow() and then reschedule ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor : How to?

Tags: java, android, threadpool

I'm working on scheduling method on button click with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.
I want the executor to be shutdown and reschedule if button is clicked again before method is executed.
I used boolean and try/catch to make this work, but executor seems only be shut down and not scheduled again.

Is this a problem of my code, or the nature of thread handling?

Below is my code.

#### JAVA

```
ScheduledTrheadPoolExecutor se = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
se.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
  se.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);

...
if (!clicked) {
  se.schedule(runnable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  clicked = true;
} else {
  try {
    se.shutdownNow();
    se.schedule(runnable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (RejectedExecutionExeption e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: After you've shut it down, it is, err, shut down. You have to create a new one before you can schedule or submit anything else.

Answer (score 0):

First set `se.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);` below `ScheduledTrheadPoolExecutor se = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);` line on top initialization.

Then after shutting down current executor reinitialize again like below:

```
    try {
       se.shutdownNow();
      // Previous Executor is terminated, but to re-schedule task again Executor has to be initialized .
       se = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
       se.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new 
       ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy());
       se.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
       se.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
       se.schedule(runnable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried ```se = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor``` but not the rest. I'll try it! Thanks for new insight